# Android JavaCV FFmpegFrameRecorder.stop() throws exception

Tags: android, ffmpeg, record, h.264, javacv

I am using FFmpegFrameRecorder to capture preview frames from camera. I am using this setting:

```
mVideoRecorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(mVideoPath, 300, 300, 1);
mVideoRecorder.setFormat("mp4");
mVideoRecorder.setSampleRate(44100);
mVideoRecorder.setFrameRate(30);
mVideoRecorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
mVideoRecorder.setAudioCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);
mVideoRecorder.setVideoQuality(0);
mVideoRecorder.setAudioQuality(0);
mVideoRecorder.setVideoBitrate(768000);
mVideoRecorder.setAudioBitrate(128000);
mVideoRecorder.setGopSize(1);
```

After I have finished capturing all frames by calling .record(IplImage) method I call mVideoRecorder.stop().

But from time to time stop() method throws

```
org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameRecorder$Exception: av_interleaved_write_frame() error -22 while writing interleaved video frame.
at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.record(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:727)
at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.stop(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:613)
```

I have not seen any regularity in this behaviour nor have been able to found what error -22 is. And after that no ffmpeg call on file in mVideoPath works (I guess that file is not even valid due that error).

I would really appreciate any help with this issue, thanks :)

Comment: I get the same error too, haven't figured out the cause yet 'll update if I find a solution.

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: If I remember correctly then this was caused by calling `stop()` too soon. It seems like ffmpeg does some stuff internally even after the `record()` already returned. But I don't really recall if this was the issue, sorry.